# ajax:CascadingDropDown set selectedIndex to 0

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have two **ajax:CascadingDropDown**, one is ***state***, one is ***county***. It worked as if user changes the ***state***, then the ***county*** will be refilled with new data. However, the problem is, once the ***county*** has the new data, the selected index remains the same. How can i set the selected index to 0 when the user changes ***state***? Thanks!

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Location_State" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

<ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="StateCascading" runat="server" Category="State" 
                        TargetControlID="Location_State" 
                        ServiceMethod="BindStateDropdown" 
                        ServicePath="CountyService.asmx">
</ajax:CascadingDropDown>

<asp:DropDownList ID="Location_County" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

<ajax:CascadingDropDown ID="CountyCascading" runat="server" Category="County" 
                        TargetControlID="Location_County"
                        ParentControlID="Location_State"
                        ServiceMethod="BindCountyDropdown" 
                        ServicePath="CountyService.asmx">
</ajax:CascadingDropDown>
```

here's the function populating the county list

```
[WebMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] BindCountyDropdown(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
{
    StringDictionary statedetails = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);
    List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> countydetails = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
    string tableName = "county";
    string sqlSQL = "";
    string sqlConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStr);
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlSQL = "SELECT [NAME], [CNTY_FIPS] FROM " + tableName + " [county] WHERE (\[STATE_FIPS] = @STATE_FIPS order by name";
    SqlCommand cmdSql = new SqlCommand(sqlSQL, sqlConn);
    ((SqlParameter)cmdSql.Parameters.Add("@STATE_FIPS", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = statedetails["State"];
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmdSql.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        countydetails.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(rdr["NAME"].ToString(), rdr["CNTY_FIPS"].ToString()));
    }
    rdr.Close();
    sqlConn.Close();
    return countydetails.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: show function you used for populating child ddl

Answer (score 0):

i fount solution myself. a simple yet working solution. 
just change the index of the ddl to 0 after 0.1 seconds, as long as the ajax request is faster than 0.1 seconds!

```
$(function () {
        $("#MainContent_Location_State").change(function () {
            setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('MainContent_Location_County').selectedIndex = 0; }, 100);
        });
});
```